# JPQL condition within list of two parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a list of two parameters (I have got it with subquery)

```
LocalDate date, Long id
LocalDate date, Long id
...
LocalDate date, Long id
```

I want to call the query to get objects, where each row is checked for two conditions:

- id is from my parameters list
- for each id taken from parameters list date should be after the one provided in paramneter list

WHERE IN seems not appliable here.

In SQL I would try with JOIN clause, but in JPQL I cannot join on subquery. How to do this with JPQL?

example:

parameters from subquery

```
2018/01/10 1
2018/01/20 2
```

Chron object table data

```
2018/01/09 1
2018/01/15 1
2018/01/25 1
2018/01/15 2
2018/01/25 2
2018/01/25 3
```

query should return Chron objects

```
2018/01/15 1
2018/01/25 1
2018/01/25 2
```

I was able to build similar query, but it takes just one ID and date as parameter, calls subquery to get just one date, while I need to provide list of IDs as input:

```
SELECT oc 
FROM OutletChron oc 
WHERE 
oc.outletId = :outletId AND 
oc.start >= (COALESCE( 
 (SELECT MAX(ocInner.start) 
  FROM OutletChron ocInner 
  WHERE 
   ocInner.outletId = :outletId AND 
   ocInner.start <= :from), :from)) 
ORDER BY oc.start
```

Comment: Why is `IN` not appliable?

Comment: because in will help to find just one parameter id or date, or you have other idea?

Comment: Nevermind it would not work because of the <=.

Comment: yes, I need sub query with <= condition and then do something with it

Comment: @Pavlo Have you tried using a Specification Query? I think that would work well for you